# How to get a recalculated copy of a complex array

Tags: excel, vba

I need to calculate an unknown complex array and get a perfect recalculated copy of it while I don't know how the array looks. For 
example:

```
MyArray = array(15, 22, array(1, array(7, 3), 9))
or
MyArray = Range("A1:B17")
or
a filled up MyArray(9, 20, 8, 3) which may contain other unknown arrays
```

To get the values, I'd normally loop with `For Each ...` which calls itself every time it finds an array inside the array. However I'm unable to put the values back in it. Let's try an easy example:

```
Sub Test()
  Dim a As Variant, b As Variant
  a = Array(1, 2)
  For Each b In a
    b = b + 1
  Next
  For Each b In a
    Debug.Print b
  Next
End Sub
```

While that's easy enough to solve it better, it still shows my problem. Having just a copy won't let me put the new value back in it. Assuming only 1-D arrays and values:

```
Function Test2(a As Variant) As Variant
  Dim i As Long
  If IsArray(a) Then
    For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
      a(i) = Test2(a(i))
    Next
    Test2 = a
  Else
    Test2 = a + 1
  End If
End Function

Sub Test3()
  Dim a As Variant
  a = Array(1, Array(2, 3))
  Debug.Print "Array(" & a(0) & ", Array(" & a(1)(0) & "," & a(1)(1) & "))"
  a = Test2(a)
  Debug.Print "Array(" & a(0) & ", Array(" & a(1)(0) & "," & a(1)(1) & "))"
End Sub
```

While this works for 1-D arrays, it won't do for n-D arrays. And still I don't know how my array will be.

Is there a workaround for unknown arrays or a way to put back values inside of a `For Each ...`-loop?

Converting `MyArray(1, 1)` to `Array(Array(,),Array(,))` looked nice at the beginning, but converting it back is kinda impossible due to the fact `Array(Array(,),Array(,))` is still a valid array to start with. Also due to possible complexity it would be as good as impossible to "remember" how it has to be put together again. At least there won't be any collection's or self-declared-types.

**Edit:**
Regarding the actual answers it may not be completely clear what I want.

```
Dim MyArray(5, 5) as Variant
MyArray(0, 0) = 7
MyArray(0, 1) = 9
...
MyArray(4, 0) = 7
...
```

This is a simple 2-D Array and my `Test2` can't handle it with a `MyArray(i)`. It will lead to an error. So each answer doing the same like my function can't be correct.

Comment: i got the idea to just use poiters which redirect to the real value... tough... i dont know how to do having just an `Array` :(

Comment: Although I still have no idea why ppl voted me down... i got my answer... yay :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim a
    a = Array(1, Array(2, Array(4, 5, 6)))
    Process a
    PrintIt a
End Sub
Sub Process(a)
    For i = 0 To UBound(a)
        If Not IsArray(a(i)) Then
            a(i) = a(i) + 1
        Else
            Process a(i)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
Sub PrintIt(a)
    For i = 0 To UBound(a)
        If Not IsArray(a(i)) Then
            Debug.Print a(i)
        Else
            PrintIt a(i)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

.

**UPDATE**

So I see that you worked on it and so I'll contribute more. My aim here is to help you and anyone reading this learn.

As I mentioned in my first comment... `Testing for rank of an array requires error handling or SAFEARRAY descriptor interrogation.`

So I'll give you both ways. You worked out one way to do the former, but to build on my answer above, here is how I would do it using VBA only:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim a, b
    b = [{11,12;13,14}]
    a = Array(1, Array(2, Array(4, 5, b)))
    Iterate a
    Iterate a, 1
End Sub
Sub Process(a)
    a = a + 1
End Sub
Sub Iterate(a, Optional bReport As Boolean = False)
    Dim rank&, i&, j&, z
    If IsArray(a) Then
        Select Case ArrayRank(a)
            Case 1
                For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
                    Iterate a(i), bReport
                Next
            Case 2
                For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
                    For j = LBound(a, 2) To UBound(a, 2)
                        Iterate a(i, j), bReport
                    Next
                Next
        End Select
    Else
        If bReport Then
            Debug.Print a
        Else
            Process a
        End If
    End If
End Sub
Function ArrayRank&(a)
    Dim j&, k&
    On Error Resume Next
    For j = 1 To 60
        k = LBound(a, j)
        If Err Then ArrayRank = j - 1: Exit For
    Next
End Function
```

And yes, using VBA only you will by necessity be required to use a hard coded switch, such as a Select Case, because of the way VBA array element\rank indexing is implemented. My updated answer above shows how to work with the first two dimensions. It would of course need additional Cases for higher ranks.

However (and again just like I said upfront) the other way is to interrogate the SAFEARRAY descriptor. This makes for a general solution, but requires a much deeper understanding of the internals of COM variables. I've shown it working with ranks 1, 2, and 3. But it should work with all ranks:

```
Private Declare Sub GetMem2 Lib "msvbvm60" (ByVal Addr As Long, RetVal As Integer)
Private Declare Sub GetMem4 Lib "msvbvm60" (ByVal Addr As Long, RetVal As Long)

Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByRef Destination As Any, ByRef Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)


Sub Test()
    Dim a, b, c
    b = [{110,120;130,140}]
    ReDim c(1 To 1, 1 To 1, 1 To 3)
    c(1, 1, 1) = 500
    c(1, 1, 2) = 600
    c(1, 1, 3) = 700
    a = Array(1, Array(2, Array(40, 50, b, c)))
    Iterate a
    Debug.Print
    Iterate a, 1
End Sub
Sub Process(a)
    a = a + 1
End Sub
Sub Iterate(a, Optional bReport As Boolean = False)
    Dim t%, dims%, elems&, bounds&(), ptr&, ptrBase&, ptrData&
    Dim rank&, c&, i&, z
    If IsArray(a) Then
        ptr = VarPtr(a)
        GetMem2 ptr, t
        If (t And 16384) = 16384 Then   'ByRef Variant Array (16384 = VT_BYREF)
            GetMem4 ptr + 8, ptr
            GetMem4 ptr, ptrBase
        Else
            GetMem4 ptr + 8, ptrBase
        End If
        GetMem4 ptrBase + 12, ptrData
        GetMem2 ptrBase, dims
        c = UBound(a) - LBound(a) + 1
        For i = 2 To dims
            c = c * (UBound(a, i) - LBound(a, i) + 1)
        Next
        For i = 0 To c - 1
            CopyMemory ByVal VarPtr(z), ByVal ptrData + i * 16, 16&
            Iterate z, bReport
            CopyMemory ByVal ptrData + i * 16, ByVal VarPtr(z), 16&
            CopyMemory ByVal VarPtr(z), 0&, 16&
        Next
    Else
        If bReport Then
            Debug.Print a
        Else
            Process a
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Note: APIs are declared for 32-bit Excel. You'll need to edit that if you wish to support 64-bit as well.

Comment: Of course it does. I provided a simple example. Testing for rank of an array requires error handling or SAFEARRAY descriptor interrogation.

Comment: Of course it won't, as is. I said it was simplified and you would need to test for higher rank and make provisions for it. But of course it can be made to do so. Think.

Comment: Recursion is not "just" a different way. It is the right way.

Comment: @DirkReichel Please have a look at the update to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This solution explores the methods to process Multidimensional Arrays and Matrix Arrays

**Matrix Arrays (range arrays):**
Assuming we want to multiply the range `B7:D12` by 15 and place the results at `H7:J12`

Use these Procedures *(see results in fig. 1)*:

```
Sub Ary_Process_Matrix()
Dim rTrg As Range
Dim aOriginal As Variant, aResult As Variant
    Set rTrg = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B7:D12")
    With rTrg
        aOriginal = .Cells
        aResult = Ary_Processor_Matrix(aOriginal)
        .Offset(0, 3 + .Columns.Count).Value = aResult
    End With
End Sub

Function Ary_Processor_Matrix(aInput As Variant) As Variant
Dim aOutput As Variant
Dim lR As Long, lC As Long

    Rem Set Output Array structure by copying it from Input Array
    aOutput = aInput

    Rem Process Input Array and Place Results in Output Array
    For lR = LBound(aInput, 1) To UBound(aInput, 1)
        For lC = LBound(aInput, 2) To UBound(aInput, 2)
            aOutput(lR, lC) = aInput(lR, lC) * 15
    Next: Next

    Rem Set Results
    Ary_Processor_Matrix = aOutput

End Function
```

[image]

*Fig. 1*

**Multidimensional Arrays:**

Assuming you have this *"Original"* `Array`:

```
aOriginal = Array( _
    Array(1, Array(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11), Array(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11), Array(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11), Array(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11), Array(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11)), _
    Array(1, 2, Array(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11), Array(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11), Array(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11), Array(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11)), _
    Array(1, 2, 3, Array(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11), Array(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11), Array(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11)), _
    Array(1, 2, 3, 5, Array(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11), Array(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11)), _
    Array(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, Array(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11)), _
    Array(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11))
```

and you want to multiply each of its members by `15`

use this function to process the *"Original"* `Array` and obtain the *Results* `Array`

```
Function Ary_Processor(aInput As Variant) As Variant
Dim aOutput As Variant
Dim l As Long

    Rem Set Output Array structure by copying it from Input Array
    aOutput = aInput

    Rem Process Input Array and Place Results in Output Array
    For l = LBound(aInput) To UBound(aInput)
        If IsArray(aInput(l)) Then
            aOutput(l) = Ary_Processor(aInput(l))
        Else
            aOutput(l) = aInput(l) * 15
    End If: Next

    Rem Set Results
    Ary_Processor = aOutput

End Function
```

And this Procedure to print both Arrays in parallel to validate the results

```
Sub Ary_Print_Arrays(aAry1 As Variant, aAry2 As Variant)
Dim l As Long
    Debug.Print "Lvl"; Tab(11); "Array 1"; Tab(21); "Array 2"
    For l = LBound(aAry1) To UBound(aAry1)
        If IsArray(aAry1(l)) Then
            Call Ary_Print_Arrays(aAry1(l), aAry2(l))
        Else
            Debug.Print l; Tab(11); aAry1(l); Tab(21); aAry2(l)
    End If: Next
End Sub
```

To process "Original" and print "Results"

```
Sub Ary_Process()
Dim aOriginal As Variant, aResult As Variant
Dim l As Long

    aOriginal = Array( _
        Array(1, Array(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11), Array(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11), Array(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11), Array(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11), Array(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11)), _
        Array(1, 2, Array(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11), Array(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11), Array(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11), Array(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11)), _
        Array(1, 2, 3, Array(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11), Array(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11), Array(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11)), _
        Array(1, 2, 3, 5, Array(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11), Array(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11)), _
        Array(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, Array(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11)), _
        Array(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11))
    aResult = Ary_Processor(aOriginal)
    Debug.Print vbLf; "Print Arrays 3D"
    Call Ary_Print_Arrays(aOriginal, aResult)

End Sub
```

[image]

This is the multidimensional "aOriginal" Array

[image]

This is the multidimensional "aResult" Array

Results can also be seen in the immediate window

Comment: Doesn't work for arrays with more than 1 dimension... sorry

Comment: The Original array has several dimensions! It's tested. See the Immediate window. what sort of errors you got?

Comment: It is a 1-D array containing 1-D arrays. `Array(x)(y) is not Array(x, y)`

Comment: Same as your example of `a = Array(1, Array(2, 3))` and MyArray = Array(15, 22, Array(1, Array(7, 3), 9))

Comment: As i had written, just asuming there only 1D arrays `Test2` will work. However, looking at the first code-window the second or third example wont work with it. Quote: _While this works for 1-D arrays, it won't do for n-D arrays. And still I don't know how my array will be._

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94087/discussion-between-eem-and-dirk-reichel).

Comment: Actually, SAFEARRAYs have a max rank of 60.