# Macro to add rows every other row

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following macro running on my Excel spreadsheet:

```
Sub yTest01()
    For i = 10 To 72 Step 2
        Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Insert
    Next i
End Sub
```

It adds a new row every other row. However, I want to add five rows each. I tried the following but it doesn't work

```
Sub yTest01()
    For i = 10 To 72 Step 2
        Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Insert
        Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Insert
        Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Insert
        Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Insert
        Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Insert
    Next i
End Sub
```

Any ideas what I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you want one line of existing data then 5 rows of blank.  Try the following

```
Sub yTest01()
For i = 72 To 10 Step -1
    Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Insert
    Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Insert
    Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Insert
    Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Insert
    Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Insert
Next i
End Sub
```

if what you want is two rows of data then five empty lines then change the step to -2

When adding or subtracting rows it is best practice to loop backwards.

Comment: To echo what @Scott-Craner said: "When adding or subtracting rows it is best practice to loop backwards." This is because when you have 10 (for example) items and add 1, you now have 11 items. So item 2 becomes item 3, 3 becomes 4, etc. When interleaving two columns of data (the "2nd" column being blank lines in you case), think of a zipper and start from the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

As a best practice I strive to reduce the number of times VBA must communicate across the boundary to Excel.

So instead of making FIVE calls across the boundary for each insertion, it's better to make one. Stepping backwards can be helpful, but its not necessary.

```
For i = 0 To 62 * 6 Step 6
    [10:10].Resize(5).Offset(i).Insert
Next
```

Note: the iteration values of 0 and 62 are simply OP's row numbers adjusted to start at zero.

Comment: @ScottCraner Have a look.

Comment: I always enjoy seeing your shortcuts.  I am here as much to learn as help.  I would be fine if @Ahmed changed this to be the correct answer.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks for those kind words. If you are interested, here's a good learning opportunity: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33489619/how-to-get-a-recalculated-copy-of-a-complex-array/33490448#33490448

Comment: @Ahmed Did you like this solution?

Answer (score 0):

why does it not work and why do you use step 2?
You could move i 5 postitions after moving the rows?

```
Sub yTest01()
Dim i As Integer
    For i = 10 To 72 Step 1
        Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Insert
        Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Insert
        Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Insert
        Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Insert
        Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Insert
        i = i + 5
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: This will not work.  Think about it, yes you will add five line then move to the next line just fine, but when you add five line then your data is past the 72nd line, by the time you get to the 72nd line in your code, where the for loop stops, over 80% of your data will be below the 72nd line and not get split up.